# How to retrieve data from firestore by fields

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to get field level data from firebase?

I want values of certain field from all documents in a collection, What should I add?
Heres my code,

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetData() {
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Reservations')
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  print(value.docs.map((e) => e.data()));
});
```

}

and this is what I get in console

```
(  461): ({}, {seats: [104A, 104B], tableNo: 104})
```

Comment: You can add screenshot about your documents and collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the method like this

```
   Future<void> fetchAndSetData() { 
         FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Reservations')
        .get()
        .then((value) { 
 print(value.docs.map((e) => e['seats']));
 }); 
}
```

Comment: Almost there, It should be like e.data()['seats'] instead of e['seats']